# Adding column in SQL where each row depends on values in other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax

I'm using SQL Server 2016. I'm trying to accomplish something in SQL that I'm not even sure is possible, and if it is, I don't even know where to start with how to implement it.

I have a table with the following columns:

case_num: ID number

Age group: 18-64, 65+

BMI: contains either a number or No BMI

BMI_flag: Normal or Abnormal based on BMI and Age

Follow_up: States whether a person had a follow up.

ServiceDate: Date visit took place. There are multiple visit dates/rows for each ID, but not the same amount of visits for each ID.

I need to create a new table and add a column called Meets_Criteria that determines whether or not a person meets the criteria.  I only care that the person is in compliance for their most recent visit, so I know I'll probably need to use rank_over_partition(). The difficulty is that there's a six month look back window.  I don't know how to have one row depend on information in other rows.

A person meets the criteria if they:

Have a BMI measurement and it's normal. Or have a normal BMI measurement in the past six months.

Have a BMI measurement, it's abnormal, and they have a follow up.  They also meet the criteria if this happened within the last six months.  The follow up does not have to occur on the same date as the abnormal BMI measurement.

If a person has a normal measurement within six months, but a more recent measurement is marked as abnormal, they must have a follow up in order to meet the criteria.

Is such a thing possible in SQL?  Which functions other than rank_over_partition should I be looking at?

This is ultimately being used in PowerBI, so I'm open to DAX solutions as well.

here is a sample table

```
    CREATE TABLE mytable(
   case_num     INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,age_group    VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
  ,BMI          VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,BMI_flag     VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
  ,Follow_Up    VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,Service_Date DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(case_num,age_group,BMI,BMI_flag,Follow_Up,Service_Date) VALUES (1111,'18-64','22','Normal','No','6/21/2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(case_num,age_group,BMI,BMI_flag,Follow_Up,Service_Date) VALUES (1111,'18-64','No BMI','Abnormal','No','6/21/2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(case_num,age_group,BMI,BMI_flag,Follow_Up,Service_Date) VALUES (2222,'18-64','30','Abnormal','Yes','6/21/2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(case_num,age_group,BMI,BMI_flag,Follow_Up,Service_Date) VALUES (2222,'18-64','No BMI','Abnormal','No','3/30/2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(case_num,age_group,BMI,BMI_flag,Follow_Up,Service_Date) VALUES (3333,'18-64','No BMI','Abnormal','No','6/21/2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(case_num,age_group,BMI,BMI_flag,Follow_Up,Service_Date) VALUES (3333,'18-64','No BMI','Abnormal','Yes','3/30/2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(case_num,age_group,BMI,BMI_flag,Follow_Up,Service_Date) VALUES (3333,'18-64','30','Abnormal','No','2/14/2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(case_num,age_group,BMI,BMI_flag,Follow_Up,Service_Date) VALUES (4444,'18-64','30','Abnormal','No','6/21/2018');
INSERT INTO mytable(case_num,age_group,BMI,BMI_flag,Follow_Up,Service_Date) VALUES (4444,'18-64','24','Normal','No','1/22/2018');
```

Below is an example what what I'd expect to see. I added a reason column for clarification:[image: Example set]

Comment: Can you give some example data to illustrate rows which would or would not be "in compliance"?

Comment: You said that you only want to check on for compliance on the most recent visit, but then state *Have a BMI measurement and it's normal. Or have a normal BMI measurement in the past six months.*. This is contradicting as is the other criteria with the *last visit* statement. It's hard to answer your question, but if you follow [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with emphasis on [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I think we could figure it out. Cheers!

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Xedni- Added an example table for clarification.

Comment: @scsimon- What I mean is that I only care if they currently meet the criteria.  This six month look back allows for this. If a person comes in today and has no measurements taken, but met the criteria last month, they still currently meet the criteria for today's visit.  The way the criteria are set up like this is why I'm having difficulty.